# Switch between file and console logger for different modules

Tags: python, logging

I have a package containing multiple modules. Modules can be called either within the `main.py` file of the package, or imported as API into other codes and modules. So, I want to implement the following logic: if `main.py` is executed and log file is provided as input, all the logging coming from modules goes into that log file and console, however, if modules are imported within any other codes, logging only does to console.

I thought of different ways of passing logger config to my modules, as well as playing with handlers, but the solution is either lame or not all the loggers writing info: some of them writing into console others to log file.

I am looking for an elegant way of implementing this logic (if any exists). From what I've read, it is not recommended to pass logger as parameters or attribute of the class, as well as having multiple loggers opening same file.

Comment: Generally (see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-handlers-other-than-nullhandler-to-a-logger-in-a-library:~:text=Adding%20handlers%20other%20than) it's the job of the consumer to decide where the logs go, so all of your modules would just emit them then either `main.py` or whatever else is importing them is responsible for providing a handler.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that makes sense. But in this case, how one would pass the choice of handler to the module?

Comment: You don't. The module doesn't receive the handler, it just gets a logger and logs to it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe okay, so the solution I see around is passing name of the logger to modules and have a context manager to change behavior of a logger within a particular module if needed.

Comment: @Olga that is nor a recommended practice - see the Python docs logging cookbook entry "Patterns to avoid".